# Java: Hangman game, 10 chances, but only 5 lives

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm creating a little mini game of Hangman. The user has 10 chances to guess, but only 5 lives.

The app works, but will continue after the 5th life, even though, I was hoping it would throw the player out of that loop.

The instantiable class (Hangman.java) is working without problems.

The secret word is "julie" as described in the instantiable class.

My App class:

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class HangmanApp {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String input, secret, result, playAgain;
    char guess;
    int i, j, k, lives;

    Hangman myHangman = new Hangman();

    do{
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello, welcome to Hangman! You have 10 chances but only 5 lives! Best of luck");

        lives = 5;

        for (j = 10; j > 0; j--) {

            while (lives >= 0){
                input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a letter");
                guess = input.charAt(0);

                //process
                myHangman.setGuess(guess);
                myHangman.compute();
                result = myHangman.getResult();

                if ((input.charAt(0) == 'j') || (input.charAt(0) == 'u') || (input.charAt(0) == 'l') || (input.charAt(0) == 'i') || (input.charAt(0) == 'e')) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That letter is in the word! Current correct letters:  " + result + ".");
                } else {
                    lives--;
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, that letter is not there. Current correct letters:  " + result + ".");
                }

                //output
                //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Current correct letters:  " + result);

            };
            lives = -1;
        }
        result = myHangman.getResult();
        secret = myHangman.getSecret();

        if (secret.equals(result)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congratulations, you got it!! The word was " + secret + ".");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, you didn't get it, better look next time! The word was " + secret + ".");
        }

        playAgain = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to play again? yes/no");

    }while (playAgain.equals("yes"));
}
```

}

Comment: Did you run through your code with a debugger?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean by "10 chances". As currently written, once `lives` hits -1, it breaks the loop, and then the `for (j = 10` loop runs another 9 times, doing nothing each time. Really, that for loop does nothing.

Comment: Yes, ran it though a debugger (using NetBeams). No errors. 

10 chances, 5 lives means that the player has a maximum chances of 10 turns, provided that get each guess right. Anywhere in those 10 chances, if all lives are lost, the game ends.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following change:

```
while (lives > 0){
```

you start at 5 and then go down to 4 3 2 1 AND 0. with the change this will stop at 0

Comment: I've tried both do-loops and while-loops, neither worked. But thank you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
    // don't need two nested cycles, you can do it in a single one
    // The cycle exits if any one of the conditions fail
    //  max attempts exhausted or all the lives are lost
    // -------------------v        v------------------------             
    for (j = 10, lives=5; j > 0 && lives > 0 ; j--) {
       // -------------------------------------^
       // j - the number of attempt is decremented for each trial,
       // no matter if successful or not

       //... the rest of cycle logic, which will decrement the lives
       //  only in cases of unsuccessful attempts

    }
```

Comment: Please explain your answer, rather than just dumping some code.

Comment: Works perfectly, exactly what I needed, I understand where I was going wrong. Thank you.

Comment: Explain my answer? I fail to understand what you mean. I said what was wrong with the code and what I was trying to do above it. ;)

Comment: @AndyTurner why? Isn't translating between the code and natural language one of the best skills a software professional can acquire? In this case, the isolation of `setGuess()`, `compute()` and `getResult()` is showing a good coding practice, but the use of the two cycles showed an unclear/fuzzy idea of what exactly one wants to do - the best practice field between code and natural language, don't you think?

Comment: @AndyTurner In principle (and most of the time an applicable one), yes. As an absolute rule, no.